# VBA using HttpClient to connect to an external REST API

Tags: vba, excel

I'm reading on some old posts that in order to connect the VBA code to an external REST API, you need to import the reference "Microsoft WinHTTP Services" and use the following code:

```
 Set req = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
```

Or Import a different reference and use the following code:

```
 Set objHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
```

These are old posts (2006, 2009) and I wonder if today (2014) Microsoft has provided something similar to HttpClient like they did for C#, VB.Net, C++

**Question:**
What is the recommended way in VBa (Excel 2013) to connect to an external REST API?

Comment: The `MSXML2.XMLHTTP` is a member of the Microsoft XML, v6.0 reference, not the WinHTTP reference.

Comment: Sorry you are right ...that's another way I noticed to connect. Which one is the latest and more reliable way to connect to an API ?

Comment: Not sure what means "the latest way", but it's standard for VBA code embedded into an Excel sheet, to reference the library (and is the straightforward way, IMHO). One other way is to declare the names that you want to use from a DLL; here's how: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb687915(v=office.15).aspx .

Comment: @CST-Link What I mean is ...what's the 2014 recommended way to connect to an API. I keep reading that those 2 options (WinHttpRequest and XMLHttp) are old ways but somehow I cannot find the new way to connect to an API....

Comment: Probably depends on the API in question but I think XMLHTTP provides a lot more flexibility, more or less compatible with [DOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model)

Comment: @DavidZemens Luckily I control the API, so that should not be an issue if I have to make changes but I wonder if you meant to know if the API returns XML? oSo to confirm you are saying that in 2014, we should still be using the MSXML2.XMLHTTP code to connect to a REST api.

Comment: @Johnny: Okay, maybe I can refine my question. You said "to connect to an API" (i.e. to connect to an Application Programming Interface), which is pretty general question. But you seem interested particularly into those two libraries. Now, the question: is your interest targeted to the particular cases, or the general case?

Comment: @CST-Link My mistake... I meant a REST API located on a public webserver. My concern is that those 2 libraries seems to have been developed long time ago and I wonder if there is a newer way to connect to a REST api.

Comment: Haven't tried this, but might be worth looking in to. https://github.com/timhall/Excel-REST

Comment: @Johnny: Sorry for wasting you time, but I don't have experience with those.

Comment: Don't worry about the age of the MSXML library - it is less old than VBA ;-)